# How to unpack the list for Elasticserach with OR operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, elasticsearch

I have a list of Term query like this

```py
term_query = [
    Terms(metadata__resource_type__subtype=["publication-softwaredocumentation"]),
    Terms(metadata__resource_type__type=["dataset"]),
]
```

I have to apply the `post_filter` with these both queries that would look like this

```py
search = search.post_filter(term_query[0] | term_query[1])
```

I want to handle situation when the `term_query` will have `0` or more elements. How can I unpack the list separated by `OR` operator in the `post_filter`?

Comment: Use script to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for the answer, I searched for any method that is available in python itself to achieve this.

I found `itertools` and `operator` modules which worked fine.

The solution looks like this

```
import itertools, operator

term_queries = [
    Terms(metadata__resource_type__subtype=["publication-softwaredocumentation"]),
    Terms(metadata__resource_type__type=["dataset"]),
]

final_query = list(itertools.accumulate(term_queries, operator.or_))[-1]
search = search.post_filter(final_query)
```